# how can I use node js mongodb connection in my local server (using wamp)?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, wamp, wampserver

I working on a website, in which I need to connect to my mongodb database (not local db), now I try to run this code (attached) on my wamp localhost but the nodejs part not running 
How can I solve it? and will this problem be in the real server too?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="aa">
    </div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "aaa";

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "aaaas";
    var uri = "mongodb://<myrealkay>:<myrealpassword>@routeplan-shard-00-00-d416l.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,routeplan-shard-00-01-d416l.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,routeplan-shard-00-02-d416l.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=routeplan-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true";
    alert(uri);
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    var collection = client.db("calc").collection("items");
   // perform actions on the collection object
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("calc");
        var a =  dbo.collection("items").find({}).toArray();
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "assaa";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you install node.js?

Comment: yes of course, its running and connecting to the db when I'm run it with cmd @RiggsFolly

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to connect to mongodb from the browser. Keep in mind that not all modules that run on Node.js are compatible with browsers. For example, you can't use the module "request" in the browser but you can use "axios". mongodb might have the same problem. The thing is, some modules depend on functions only available to Node.js and not native to javascript